# R Populate specific vectors in a matrix with names from an index

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

I'm writing script to reformat data and I'm having trouble populating it with the right values/names.

The data starts as:

```
data1=

    Date         conc1   conc2   conc3
    Control      XXXX    XXXX    XXXX
    Control      XXXX    XXXX    XXXX
    Control      XXXX    XXXX    XXXX
    Treatment1   XXXX    XXXX    XXXX
    Treatment1   XXXX    XXXX    XXXX
    Treatment1   XXXX    XXXX    XXXX
```

and needs to end up as

```
formatdata1=

    Treatment    conc    value
    Control      conc1   XXXX
    Control      conc1   XXXX
    Control      conc1   XXXX
    Control      conc2   XXXX
    Control      conc2   XXXX
    Control      conc2   XXXX
    Control      conc3   XXXX
    Control      conc3   XXXX
    Control      conc3   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc1   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc1   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc1   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc2   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc2   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc2   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc3   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc3   XXXX
    Treatment1   conc3   XXXX
```

Currently I've pre-allocated a matrix of the correct dimensions:

```
formatdata1<-array(0,dim=c(nrow(data1[+1])*ncol(data1[-1])+1,3))
```

indexed unique Treatment names:

```
unik<-!duplicated(data2[,1])
ind<-seq_along(data2[,1])[unik]
Treatname<-data.frame(data2[,1][unik]) #extracted the unique names
```

And filled the first row of the matrix with headings:

```
formatdata1[1,]=c("Treatment","Conc","Value")
```

So what I'd like to do now is fill the remainder of column 1 of `formatdata` with the correct number of treatment names, using `ind` and `Treatname`.

What I have currently is a line that reads like this:

```
formatdata1[ind[1]+1:((ind[2]-1)*ncol(data2[-1])),1]<-Treatname[1,1]
```

This does fill the correct number of cells (so i believe my indexing is right), however, instead of the treatment name i want (in this case `Control`) it is filled with just `1`.

How do I get it to use the name instead of the number? I assume there's something I can add to `<-Treatname[1,1]`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to unpivot your original data table.  Am I making a correct assumption?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Having just looked up what unpivot means, yes, that's exactly it!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would `melt` be the correct function to use here? I guess that would save me a lot of indexing and filling the matrix manually.

Comment: Yup.  Posting something now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `melt()` function which is part of the `reshape` R package:

```
library(reshape)
data1 <- data.frame(Date=c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment1", "Treatment1"),
                    conc1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    conc2=c(2,4,6,8,10,12),
                    conc3=c(3,6,9,12,15,18))

data1.melt <- melt(data1, id = c("Date"))

> data1.melt[order(data1.melt$Date),]
        Date  variable value
1    Control     conc1     1
2    Control     conc1     2
3    Control     conc1     3
7    Control     conc2     2
8    Control     conc2     4
9    Control     conc2     6
13   Control     conc3     3
14   Control     conc3     6
15   Control     conc3     9
4  Treatment1    conc1     4
5  Treatment1    conc1     5
6  Treatment1    conc1     6
10 Treatment1    conc2     8
11 Treatment1    conc2    10
12 Treatment1    conc2    12
16 Treatment1    conc3    12
17 Treatment1    conc3    15
18 Treatment1    conc3    18
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I just needed to know a function already existed!

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `dplyr/tidyr`.  We `gather` from 'wide' to 'long' format and then `arrange` the rows based on 'Date', 'conc', columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(data1, conc, value, -Date) %>% 
                  arrange(Date, conc)
#           Date  conc value
#1     Control conc1     1
#2     Control conc1     2
#3     Control conc1     3
#4     Control conc2     2
#5     Control conc2     4
#6     Control conc2     6
#7     Control conc3     3
#8     Control conc3     6
#9     Control conc3     9
#10 Treatment1 conc1     4
#11 Treatment1 conc1     5
#12 Treatment1 conc1     6
#13 Treatment1 conc2     8
#14 Treatment1 conc2    10
#15 Treatment1 conc2    12
#16 Treatment1 conc3    12
#17 Treatment1 conc3    15
#18 Treatment1 conc3    18
```